# Angular - conditional style incorrect until interaction with the page

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and I am trying to create a program that tallies up all the errors it finds in our source files.  I have the main component which loads in the modules and each module loads in the methods for that module.

- The error count on each method is that method's error count.
- The error count on each module is the sum of that module's methods error
  counts.
- The total errors displayed up top is the total of all the
  modules errors.

If there are errors at any level, that error count is display in a red bubble.  A green bubble with a checkmark will display if there are no errors.

The problem I am having is that the total error number is correct when the page first loads, but displays with a green bubble and check mark.  Once I interact with the page (expand any of the modules by clicking on the module header or removing a module by clicking on the "x"), the correct styles become applied to the total count.  I am using the same variable `totalErrorCount` to display the numeric count and to determine the styles.

**Question:**

Why does the numeric value load correctly, but the styles are calculated incorrectly before interaction?

**Incorrect (on page load, before interaction):**

[image: incorrect total count display]

**Correct (after interaction):**

[image: correct total count display (after interaction)]

**Relevant excerpt from main component HTML:**

```
<div>
    Total Errors: <span class="header-badge" [ngClass]="{'has-error': totalErrorCount > 0, 'fa fa-check': totalErrorCount === 0}">{{totalErrorCount}}</span>
</div>
```

**Relevant excerpt from main component SCSS:**

```
.header-badge {
    background-color: #008000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 17px;
    margin: -3px 6px 0 0;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 15px;
    color: #fff;

    &.has-error {
        background-color: #8b0000;
    }

    &.has-warning {
        background-color: #ea800f;
        margin-right: 6px;
    }

    &.has-info {
        background-color: #6495ed;
        margin-right: 6px;
    }
}
```

**Relevant excerpt from component class (main):**

```
export class DocumentationHelperComponent {
    private helperResults: any;
    private moduleKeys: Array<String>;
    private totalErrorCount: number;

    constructor(
        private documentationHelperService: DocumentationHelperService,
    ) {}

    getResults(): void {
        this.documentationHelperService.getResults()
            .then((results) => {
                this.helperResults = results;
                this.moduleKeys = Object.keys(this.helperResults);
            });
    }

    getTotalErrorCount(totalErrors=0): Number {
        this.totalErrorCount += totalErrors;
        return this.totalErrorCount;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.totalErrorCount = 0;
        this.getResults();
    }
}
```

**Relevant excerpt from component class (module):**

```
export class DocumentationHelperModuleComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() moduleName: String;
    @Input() moduleData: any;
    private showContents: Boolean;
    private methodKeys: Array<String>;
    private methodLength: Number;
    private hideModule: Boolean;
    private totalErrors: number;

    @Output() onTotalErrorsCounted: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>(); 

    constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }

    updateTotalErrors(errorCount): void {
        this.totalErrors += errorCount; 
        this.onTotalErrorsCounted.emit(errorCount);
    }

    decrementErrorCount(theseErrors): Number {
        this.totalErrors = theseErrors;
        this.onTotalErrorsCounted.emit( -1 * this.totalErrors);
        return this.totalErrors; 
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.showContents = false;
        this.methodKeys = Object.keys(this.moduleData);
        this.methodLength = this.methodKeys.length;
        this.hideModule = false;
        this.totalErrors = 0;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there is any other code I should provide in order to seek help.

Comment: What is in default style, i.e header-badge?

Comment: @Vega Thank you for the fast response.  The relevant scss has been added to my question.

Comment: Probably the calculation of totalErrorCount is not well 'placed' in your code, your interaction triggers it and meantime the default green color from header-badge is applied

Comment: @Vega The numeric total does update though without interaction.  Is there a way I can force ngClass to re-evaluate whenever totalErrorCount is updated?

Comment: Please post a snipet of your component class where you initialize and updated totalErrorCount

Comment: @Vega Thank you so much for helping me with this.  Additional code has been included.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148912/discussion-between-vega-and-jennifer-goncalves).